# Pretty Print XML via method using ModelAndView

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, xml-parsing, spring-thymeleaf

I have below working for xml but the formatting is not returned.

ModelAndView getUserInfo(…

I need a way to parse the ModelAndView Object xml but since getModel doesn’t pass back the string value of the xml, I haven’t been able to use Document functionality.

The xml is displaying as one line, I want to change as little as possible, currently using templates and would like to use thymeleaf too.

I’ve tried multiple methods to stylize the xml response returned from the ModelAndView, it still returns the xml on one line. I have tried using @XmlRootElement and @XmlAttribute on the DTOs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.